# calculating the width of children blocks in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to create 3 columns on a page and I want to give a padding of 20px to each column and a magin-right of 20px to columns 1 and 2, my question now is how do I calculate the width for each column given a page of width 960px? I am jsut a newbie in web and would like to know how to get the width calcuations correctly? Does, the padding adds to the width of a page? How about the border?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (960-3*40-2*20) / 3 = 800 / 3 = 266px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding and the border width are both adds to the width of your element (your column).
Margin will not effect your column's width but will be included in your general page width.

You can read about the Box Model [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)

In your case,

```
column 1: 20 + X + 20

column 2: 20 + x + 20

column 3: 20 + X + 20
```

margin after 1 and 2: `20 + 20`

so...

8*20 + 3X = 960

x = 266.6666... (your column's width)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading [this CSS tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/). Get a good understanding of the [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box_model):

> In CSS, each [element] is described using the standard box model. This model describes the content of the space taken by an element. Each box has four edges: the margin edge, border edge, padding edge, and content edge.

So, basically:

> Width = width + padding-left + padding-right + border-left + border-right

Read up and understand that, along with the basics of CSS positioning. Then you can look into setting `box-sizing` to something else (you'll see `border-box` used a lot, particularly in responsive design. It is (arguably) a more logical approach, but it is important to properly get a handle on the standard model if you wish to progress at all. IE7 (if it's even on your radar) does not support `box-sizing`.

Firebug and/or the Chrome dev tools are your best friend at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple layers that are added to an elment (see [Box-Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)).

Usually when you set a width, adding a padding will alter the size of your element, which is a bit unintuitive. However most browsers support the css-attribute `box-sizing`, which alters the way width (and height) is calculated:

Values:

```
box-sizing: content-box;
    width = content

box-sizing: padding-box;
    width = content + padding (added to the spec later, less support)

box-sizing: border-box;      
    width = content + padding + border (easiest to understand, recommended)

box-sizing: margin-box;      
    width = content + padding + margin (quite useless)
```

As I said, on most projects I'd heavily recommend `box-sizing: border-box;` because it is widely supported and most intuitive. You may need to prefix it. I'll do it mostly like that (Shotgun approach):

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Please see [w3c School](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) for the full documentation and [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing) for an overview of browser support.

Comment: wow, thanks for that link. wasn't aware about that... what would you recommend as an alternative?

Comment: The [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs) has always been strong on JS, and the CSS information there is increasingly complete. It's also a wiki, so we can help improve things further :)